# C++ Nested Iterator Class (In Linked List Class) Insert_After Function

Tags: c++, insert, iterator

I have an iterator class nested in a LinkedList class. My question is how do I make the insert_after function using iterators. The rest of the code is given for information purposes, but the function I'm trying to get working is at the end.

Insert_After takes a position and inserts a value after it.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<T> {
private:
    struct Node {

    T data; // data can be any type
    Node* next; // points to the next Node in the list

    Node(const T& d, Node* n) : data(d), next(n) {}
};
Node* head; // Is a pointer

class Iterator
{
private:
    Node* iNode;
public:
    Iterator(Node* head) : iNode(head){ }
    ~Iterator() {}
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const { return iNode != rhs.iNode; }
    Iterator& operator++() { iNode = iNode->next; return *this; }
    T& operator*() const { return iNode->data; }
};

/** Return iterator pointing to the first value in linked list */
Iterator begin(void) {
    return LinkedList<T>::Iterator(head); 
}

/** Return iterator pointing to something not in linked list */
Iterator end(void) {
    return LinkedList<T>::Iterator(NULL); 
}

/** Return iterator pointing found value in linked list */
Iterator find(Iterator first, Iterator last, const T& value) {
    Iterator current = first;
    bool found = false;
    while (current != last) {
        if (*current == value) {
            return current;
        }

        ++current;
    }

    return last;
}

Iterator insert_after(Iterator position, const T& value)
{
    // Need help here
}
```

What I've tried so far resulted in a few errors.

```
Iterator insert_after(Iterator position, const T& value)
{
    // Need to insert after position
    Iterator previous = position;
    ++position;
    Node* newNode = new Node(value, position);
    previous->next = newNode;

}
```

The error I got was Error C2664 'function' : cannot convert argument n from 'type1' to 'type2' for the line

```
Node* newNode = new Node(value, position);
```

Compiler Error C2819 type 'type' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' for line

```
previous->next = newNode;
```

I understand the errors but I'm not sure how to work around them.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what errors do you get.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your compiler errors is that you are likely supposed to pass a `Node` or `Node*` as your second argument and not an iterator. `previous` is also an iterator, and therefore does not have a `next` call.

*Long answer below about generally fixing the function in question:*
There's a lot [not] going on in that function, which gets me wondering about the rest of the linked list class as well. I've only looked at this function, as it's the one you claim is causing you trouble.

**SUBJECTIVE THOUGHT** I generally hate working with iterators in my class functions. Deal with the Nodes directly as much as possible. The iterator pattern exists for universal traversal of containers no matter how they're laid out, and that abstraction makes it a pain to deal with inside your class.

```cpp
Iterator insert_after(Iterator position, const T& value)
{
    // Need to insert after position
    Iterator previous = position;
    ++position;
    Node* newNode = new Node(value, position);
    previous->next = newNode;

}
```

As it currently stands, if `position` is anywhere but the last element, you will break your list and leak memory. This is because you never check what is after `position`. That first mistake leads into the second. `newNode->next` never gets set. Maybe it's default constructed to `nullptr`, that's fine. But if I'm inserting into the middle of my list, I need to connect `newNode` to whatever came after `position` originally.

Another question that you need to consider is "what if this is called on an empty list?" Does your `begin()` function handle that? Is it supposed to throw?

```cpp
Iterator insert_after(Iterator position, const T& value)
{
    Node* pos = position.iNode;

    if (!pos) {  // assumes an empty list if this is true
        // Correctly build first Node of your list and get everything assigned
        // that you can
        // return the new iterator;

        // or just throw
    }

    if (!pos->next) {  // position at end of list if true
        pos->next = new Node(value, position);  // Is that second argument
                                                // supposed to be an iterator?
        return Iterator(pos->next);
    } else {
        // Some of this is probably redundant depending on how you are actually
        // building Nodes, but the gist is it's important to ensure the list is
        // not broken; connecting tmp before changing existing nodes helps the
        // list stay intact for as long as possible
        Node* tmp = new Node(value, position);
        tmp->next = pos->next;
        pos->next = tmp;

        return Iterator(tmp);
    }
```

A doubly linked list never seems attractive at first blush to a student, but it makes certain operations like erasing from the middle of the list so much easier. Yes, you have one extra pointer to deal with, but it makes it harder to lose Nodes as well. Along with bi-directional iteration.